# libxml2,libxml2-dev installed but still fails to configure in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, libxml2

I am trying to install lalsuite of LIGO. I installed all the dependencies. While configuring it is giving the following error for *lalxml*.

```
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes  
checking for LIBXML2... no  
checking for xmlInitParser in -lxml2... yes  
checking libxml/tree.h usability... no  
checking libxml/tree.h presence... no  
checking for libxml/tree.h... no  
configure: error: could not find the libxml/tree.h header  
configure: error: ./configure failed for lalxml
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04LTS and the installed libxml2 version is

```
libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.5).
```

Answer (score -1):

First remove old version.

> sudo apt remove --purge libxml2 libxml2-dev
> (Warning: this will uninstall all packages that are dependent on libxml)
> Then update

> sudo apt update

Finally install again.

> sudo apt install libxml2 libxml2-dev

Comment: _libxml2_,_libxml2-dev_ could not be removed due to some dependencies issues.   It says The following packages have unmet dependencies: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: »»libxml2 is already the newest version«« : `libxml2` provides run time files. The package for building applications with libxml2 : `sudo apt install libxml2-dev`. ... And : No reason at all for removing any packages !

Comment: __libxml2 and libxm2-dev__ both were installed properly. The problem was with **PKG_CONFIG_PATH.** The config folder containing the header files were not added to the **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** variable. Now, the problem is solved.

Comment: @santanutripathy Can you help me to to this issue. I am unable correct PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable value.

Comment: Warning guys!! this uninstalled all packages that depend on libxml

Comment: @santanutripathy You have stated that the problem has been resolved. In this case, you can help other users by answering your own question in detail and end this topic.